# How can I truncate table and cascade with bulkDelete in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a seed and I use bulkDelete with query interface. It's okay but I need to truncate table. I set truncate: true options and I get an error:

> Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (vexus_panel.visits, CONSTRAINT visits_ibfk_4 FOREIGN KEY (countryId) REFERENCES vexus_panel.countries (id))

And then I enable cascade like this: cascade: true but still not working

My code:

```
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    /**
     * Add commands to revert seed here.
     *
     * Example:
     * await queryInterface.bulkDelete('People', null, {});
     */
    await queryInterface.bulkDelete("Countries", null, {
      truncate: true,
      cascade: true,
    });
  },
```

Error:

> ERROR: Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`vexus_panel`.`visits`, CONSTRAINT `visits_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`countryId`) REFERENCES `vexus_panel`.`countries` (`id`))

Docs: [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-bulkDelete](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js%7EQueryInterface.html#instance-method-bulkDelete)

**Update:**

I found a solution.

```
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    const { sequelize } = queryInterface;
    try {
      await sequelize.transaction(async (transaction) => {
        const options = { transaction };
        await sequelize.query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0", options);
        await sequelize.query("TRUNCATE TABLE Countries", options);
        await sequelize.query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1", options);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Disable the [constraint](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/query-interface.js%7EQueryInterface.html#instance-method-removeConstraint), for the truncation

```
queryInterface.removeConstraint(vexus_panel.visits,visits_ibfk_4  )
```

And when you are done add it again

Comment: If I do this I need add constraint again.I need easier way. I using Sequelize v6.3.5

Comment: there is no easier way to fo that in sequlize, in mysql you would also disable all constraints and then enable them again, but as you want a sequlize solution, this is the way. Besides you program this onece and run it everytimeyou truncate, how much easier should it get

Comment: I found a solutions. Can you check the edited question?

Comment: That is the same as my solution but you disable all constraints mine only one and it is not easier